# How to resolve the issue that is prohibiting me to boot up my VMWare?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, kali-linux, vmware-workstation

I am getting this message when I tried to run my kali linux through VMWare.

"VMware Workstation cannot connect to the virtual machine. Make sure you have rights to run the program, access all directories the program uses, and access all directories for temporary files. Failed to connect pipe to virtual machine: The system cannot find the file specified."

I did everything that has been told in this article, which was killing all processes in the VMWare and starting the VMWare Authorization again. Also did reboot on main OS (Windows 10) but none of this work for me: Error while powering on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328292/error-while-powering-on-vmware-player-cannot-connect-to-the-virtual-machine

So my final alternatives could be, I will need to completely uninstall VMWare and reinstall it. But how about the data in the Kali Linux that I was trying to open? Is there any methods that I could recover it?

Comment: I am posting from a Kali Machine in VMware Workstation on a Windows 10 Host. Make sure you have a back up of your Kali machine, uninstall Workstation, restart the host computer, install Workstation again, restart (part of the Workstation install) and try running Kali again.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your respond. May I know how can I perform a backup? Do I need to get boot up the kali linux since I could not do due to the above matters

Comment: Go to the VMware folder and copy the Kali folder to another, non-VMware location (don't move it, just copy it).  Reinstalling VMware Workstation typically does not harm a machine. I have done this before.